# How to install Kernel Modules from Source Code. Error while make process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, arm

I want to install the kernel modules to lib/modules/ . Actually there has to be created a folder in lib/modules/(uname-r) after doing `make modules` , but there are only created 3 folders called "build", "kernel" and "source". I also get an error after `make modules`:

```
DEPMOD 3.4.79
WARNING: COULDN't open directory /lib/modules/3.4.79: No such file or direcoty
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.4.79/modules.dep.temp for writing: No suhc file or directory
make: *** [_modinst_post] Error 1
```

Indeed there is no directory called that, but how can I add it?

Comment: Have you compiled the kernel? These directories are generated after the kernel has been built.

Comment: i compiled it with "make" in the kernel source

Comment: Just to state the obvious since you've not mentioned it, looking at my box /lib/modules/ is only root-writable - you _do_ have the right permissions, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try \"make modules_install\"?

to install modules

make modules_install

to install kernel

make install

Comment: yes i did, there are built 3 folders called build, kernel, source. there is also 2 files called modules.builtin and modules.order

Answer (score 0):

**Out-of-tree modules**

For the benefit of future Googlers, this is what [Buildroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buildroot) 2018.05 does to install out-of-tree modules for LInux v4.19:

```
cd linux_kernel_source
mkdir -p /build/dir/default/x86_64/target/lib/modules/4.19.0/extra
/usr/bin/make -f ./scripts/Makefile.modinst
mkdir -p /build/dir/default/x86_64/target/lib/modules/4.19.0/extra
cp /build/dir/default/x86_64/build/kernel_modules-1.0/./buildroot_dep.ko /build/dir/default/x86_64/target/lib/modules/4.19.0/extra
/build/dir/default/x86_64/host/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-uclibc-strip --strip-debug /build/dir/default/x86_64/target/lib/modules/4.19.0/extra/buildroot_dep.ko
/bin/bash ./scripts/depmod.sh /build/dir/default/x86_64/host/sbin/depmod 4.19.0
```

So we can see that it uses the `./scripts/Makefile.modinst` and `./scripts/depmod.sh` in tree scripts, plus some ugly manual copying of the modules.

Found by building [a package that contains kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307328/how-to-add-a-linux-kernel-driver-module-as-a-buildroot-package) with `V=1` and `kernel_modules_package_name-reconfigure` and simplifying the output commands, works every time :-).

The only missing question is how `depmod` was obtained, so we do another verbose build with `host-kmod-reconfigure`, and basically obtain:

```
./configure
--prefix="/build/dir/default/x86_64/host"
--sysconfdir="/build/dir/default/x86_64/host/etc"
--localstatedir="/build/dir/default/x86_64/host/var"
```

where the source is obtained from: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git

In tree modules are installed with `make modules_install` as mentioned at: [How to install Kernel Modules from Source Code. Error while make process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783793/how-to-install-kernel-modules-from-source-code-error-while-make-process/22800896#22800896)