# Is it possible to use config fragments with Buildroot's .config?

Tags: buildroot

I'm using Buildroot as a submodule, and I want to reuse existing in-tree defconfigs with a few modification of my own.

I'd like to store just the modified options in a config fragment, just like I can do with `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES` for the Linux kernel config.

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
cd buildroot
make BR2_EXTERNAL="$(pwd)/../mypackage" qemu_x86_64_defconfig
echo '
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="../kernel_config_fragment"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="../rootfs_overlay"
' >> .config
make
```

Is there a nicer way to avoid that `echo` with a config fragment, just like I'm using for the Linux kernel config fragment? I'd expect something like:

```
make BR2_CONFIG_FRAG=br_config_frag
```

where `br_config_frag` contains the lines:

```
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="../kernel_config_fragment"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="../rootfs_overlay"
```

and then I'd be able to write just:

```
make -C buildroot BR2_CONFIG_FRAG=br_config_frag qemu_x86_64_defconfig all
```

Here's the full [example repo](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f367ffc6cfafb07c8e10a8a2740f3133a7bea765).

**Edit**

One slight improvement is to put the "config fragment" in a separate file `buildroot_config_fragment`:

```
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES="../kernel_config_fragment"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="../rootfs_overlay"
```

and then `cat` that:

```
cat ../buildroot_config_fragment >> .config
```

Comment: a quick question Ciro, I am trying to test a kernel module and have a config fragment for it in my kernel source subdirectory, what's an easy way to pull that in to a buildroot?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Hi Ahmed, I don't understand exactly what you mean by "a config fragment in my kernel source". Is that a Linux kernel config fragment? To just add a kernel module to Buildroot, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307328/how-to-add-a-linux-kernel-driver-module-as-a-buildroot-package/43874273#43874273

Comment: Hehe I figured it out. Will write a gist. Yes it was a kernel config fragment that I wanted to append to the default arch config

Answer (score 3):

First side note: your script should run `make olddefconfig` before `make`, so that any new options are set to their default value instead of being asked for interactively.

You could simplify the script a little by doing:

```
cat configs/qemu_x86_64_defconfig br_config_frag > .config
make olddefconfig
```

You can also use the script `support/kconfig/merge_config.sh` from the kconfig infrastructure. However, that script internally uses `make alldefconfig` which currently doesn't work - you need [a patch](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/748188/) for that.

If you would like to add support for `BR2_CONFIG_FRAG` to the Buildroot infrastructure, feel free to send a patch to [the Buildroot mailing list](http://lists.busybox.net/mailman/listinfo/buildroot)!

Comment: Thanks Arnout. I knew about `olddefconfig`, but what does `alldefconfig` do? Is the patch just changing those 3 lines, or are there more changes? I can't use that patchwork thing :-)

Comment: alldefconfig does the same as olddefconfig, but instead of starting from an existing .config file, it starts from a config file passed in through the `KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG` environment variable. I think the main difference is that when you interrupt the process, the old `.config` doesn't get overwritten. For using patchwork: there is a "download patch" link; you can apply the downloaded patch with `patch -p1`.

Answer (score 1):

I asked on the IRC, and an user who seems to be Yann E. Morin, who seems to be an active developer, said it is not possible currently.

Answer (score 0):

Arnout's `make alldefconfig` patch is now merged in buildroot as of 26 Jul 2017
(https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/dab80981d15979eab3aea28a33694396635a52a1).

This means you can now do:

```
./support/kconfig/merge_config.sh configs/qemu_x86_64_defconfig fragment1.config fragment2.config
```

This will use `qemu_x86_64_defconfig` as the base and add modifications given in the listed fragment config files. The tool will also show nice warnings if you override items.